# How to change windows phone APP language during runtime?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-7, multilingual

I followed this example to build a multilingual app: [How to: Build a Localized Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

I successfully bound the resource data to text like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="{Binding Path=MultiLangResources.Mainpage_Welcome, Source={StaticResource MultiLang}}"/>
```

And I tried to change the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and I can output correct key with code:

```
ApplicationTitle.Text = LangResource.Mainpage_Welcome;
```

However, the bound text never update.

How to make the bound text update like ordinary bind?

Is there anyone could help me with this problem?
I also tried this with no luck.

```
public class MultiLang : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MultiLang()
    {
    }

    private static MLTest.LangResource multiLangResources = new GigapodV2.LangResource();

    public MLTest.LangResource MultiLangResources
    {
        get { return multiLangResources; }
        set
        {
            if (value != multiLangResources)
            {
                multiLangResources = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MultiLangResources");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LangResource` class isn't observable by itself, and thus any bound properties from it won't be observed. And also, the phone won't notify all properties that's related to the CurrentCulture just because you change it on-the-fly.

Language change in that fashion would otherwise require a reboot of your app. But I would advice you to be careful with this, as the OS itself allows language swapping, meaning you need to have a **really** good reason for your app to allow it in itself.

The solution is to create a wrapper class, that notifies all properties that they been updated, when you change the CurrentCulture. Using Simon's [NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver)'s [DependsOn] attribute could probably make this very easy.

Answer (score 4):

It can be easily done:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ca-ES");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ca-ES");
```

The main problem is that the text on all the pages that are ALREADY loaded (for example the main page, if you put the language choose there), will need to be "manually refreshed".

But this can be easily done programatically:

```
this.btnChangeLanguage.Content = AppResources.Txt_Aceptar;
```